# Как сделать автоматическое сложение или вычитание

Tags: c#, winforms

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно сделать так, что если я добавляю новую строку с данными в БД, вставленную в datagridview, эта строка сама инициализировалась по типу (доход или расход) и соответственно автоматически добавлялась к итоговой сумме "Дохода" или автоматически вычиталась от итоговой суммы "Расхода". чтобы не вводить на каждую добавленную строку отдельный код. если можно объяснить подробно, потому что я пока разбираюсь в этом и могу чего то не понять, буду признателен

Код добавления новой строки:

```
private void AddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Form1 main = this.Owner as Form1;
    if (main != null) {
        DataRow nRow = main.база_данныхDataSet.Tables[0].NewRow();
        int rc = main.dataGridView1.RowCount + 1;
        nRow[0] = rc;
        nRow[1] = tbType.Text;
        nRow[2] = tbCategory.Text;
        nRow[3] = tbDate.Text;
        nRow[4] = tbSum.Text;
        // nRow[5] = tbTotal.Text;
        nRow[6] = tbComments.Text;

        main.база_данныхDataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Add(nRow);
        main.accountingTableAdapter.Update(main.база_данныхDataSet.Accounting);
        main.база_данныхDataSet.Tables[0].AcceptChanges();
        main.dataGridView1.Refresh();
        tbType.Text = " ";
        tbCategory.Text = " ";
        tbDate.Text = " ";
        tbSum.Text = " ";
        // tbTotal.Text = " ";
        tbComments.Text = " ";
    }
}
```

[image: Вот приблизительно изобразил как надо чтобы получалось]

Код, который вычисляет сумму и разность, прописанный вручную, действующий только на имеющиеся строки.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
    dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[5].Value = Convert.ToString(Double.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[4].Value.ToString()));
    dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[5].Value = Convert.ToString(Double.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[5].Value.ToString()) + Double.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[4].Value.ToString()));
    dataGridView1.Rows[2].Cells[5].Value = Convert.ToString(Double.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[5].Value.ToString()) + Double.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[2].Cells[4].Value.ToString()));
    dataGridView1.Rows[3].Cells[5].Value = Convert.ToString(Double.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[2].Cells[5].Value.ToString()) - Double.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[3].Cells[4].Value.ToString()));
    dataGridView1.Rows[4].Cells[5].Value = Convert.ToString(Double.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[3].Cells[5].Value.ToString()) - Double.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[4].Cells[4].Value.ToString()));
    dataGridView1.Rows[5].Cells[5].Value = Convert.ToString(Double.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[4].Cells[5].Value.ToString()) - Double.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[5].Cells[4].Value.ToString()));
}
```

Comment: А какая формула для вычисления Итого?

Comment: обычное сложение или вычитание. например из картинки если добавляю Тип - Доход и его Сумму - 10 000 000, то  эта сумма должна прибавиться к последней имеющейся Сумме с таким же Типом - Доход и Сумма - 7 000 000. и в Итого должно получиться Сумма = 10 000 000 + 7 000 000  при этом значения те что после 7 000 000. т.е Расход естественно должны меняться. как то так.

Comment: Вы гуманитарий что-ли? `обычное сложение или вычитание`, `Расход естественно должны меняться. как то так`. Конкретная формула имеется или нет?

Comment: что вы имеете ввиду под конкретной формулой?

Comment: @Bulson Итого[i]=Итого[i-1] + (Тип[i] == "Доход" ? 1 : -1) * Сумма[i]

Comment: @Никита не ясно, что именно у вас не получилось сделать

Comment: @4per понимаете я первые пять строк из таблицы прописывал вручную. я понимаю что таблица не совсем правильная но таково задание. так вот я хочу чтоб при добавлении новой строки она автоматически как то инициализировалась по типу и в зависимости от этого Cумма либо прибавлялась к строке Итого (Id - 3) или отнималось от Итого (Id - 6)

Comment: Итого, я бы переименовал в баланс или остаток. У вас порядок строк меняется? Просто вычислите формулу, которую я привёл выше

Comment: @4per порядок может меняться как и первые 6 строк введеные в базе данных изначально так и при добавление новых строк в рандомном порядке.

Comment: А вам нужно вычислять это в приложении, или можно в СУБД? Некоторые или даже многие СУБД, умеют вычислять такие штуки.

Comment: @4per а как эту формулу в код преобразовать правильно? и где его лучше применить? в кнопке добавления строк или в главной форме  в dataGridView1_CellContentClick, где я в ручную прописывал сумму и вычитание?

Comment: по идее в добавлении, правда я не понял с момента "или в главной форме"

Comment: я знаю что в экселе можно с помощью постановки формул вычислять. в аксесе не знаю. у меня бд в аксесе. но при добавлении новой строки она ведь добавляется в БД.

Comment: @4per добавил код который у меня в Form1.cs

Comment: Я уверен, вы должны знать что такое цикл for

Comment: @4per если честно то нет. я пытаюсь познать на практике.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void ButtonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //если это не первая запись в таблице
        if (_dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            //сначала находим максимальный Id
            var lastId = _dataSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Max(r => r.Field<int>("Id"));
            //находим последнюю запись
            var lastRow = _dataSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                                       .First(r => r.Field<int>("Id") == lastId);

            //вычисляем значение Итого
            decimal lastTotal = lastRow.Field<decimal>("Total");
            string type = _comboBoxType.Text;
            decimal current = 0;
            if (decimal.TryParse(_textBoxSum.Text, out decimal sum))
            {
                current = (type.Equals("Доход") ? 1 : -1) * sum;
            }
            //создаем новую строку
            var row = _dataSet.Tables[0].NewRow();
            row["Type"] = type;
            row["Category"] = _comboBoxCategory.Text;
            row["Date"] = _dateTimePicker.Value;
            row["Sum"] = sum;
            row["Total"] = lastTotal + current;
            _dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Add(row);
        }
        else
        {
            // в случае первой записи в таблицу...
        }

        //пишем в БД
        try
        {
            using (var adp = new SqlDataAdapter(_selectString, _conString))
            using (var cmb = new SqlCommandBuilder(adp))
            {
                var added = adp.Update(_dataSet.Tables[0]);
                Trace.WriteLine($"Добавлено {added}");
            }
            _dataSet.Tables[0].AcceptChanges();
            _dataGridView.Refresh();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: // в случае первой записи в таблицу...   в else что значит?

Comment: Это значит что вам нужно написать самостоятельно вставку первой записи в пустую таблицу в разделе else.

Comment: то есть код который я изначально присвоил AddButton должен вставить в else? я правильно понял?

Comment: По логике вещей да, только у первой записи Итого == Сумма, не так ли?

Comment: да  так. сумма второй записи прибавляется к итого первой записи

Comment: _comboBoxType, _textBoxSum, _comboBoxCategory, _dateTimePicker, Trace - вот эти у меня подчеркиваются и появляется ошибка. остальные исправил. а эти не существуют в текущем контексте.

Comment: конечно не существуют, это я так назвал контролы на форме, у вас свои названия контролов. По-моему, это очевидно же.

Comment: Наверное, но все равно не совсем понятно.

Comment: я попробовал запустил ваш код с использованием своих котролов, вышло необработанное исключение при попытке добавить новую строку decimal lastTotal = lastRow.Field<decimal>("Итого"); System.InvalidCastException: "Заданное приведение является недопустимым." Если так decimal lastTotal = lastRow.Field<decimal>("Total"); то `System.ArgumentException: "Столбец "Total" не принадлежит таблице Accounting."`